# Is it possible to have a count down timer continue running even after the user has closed the app

Tags: java, android, mobile, timer, pthreads

Im thinking of having an android app that has a count down timer. However, i need this timer to be running too even if the user kills the app and once the count down timer reaches 00:00:00, it triggers an action regardless of the application being active. Is there a possible solution to that?

Comment: you should know about services

Comment: Yes it is very possible, use a service ^

Comment: @SHASHIDHARMANCHUKONDA would services stay alive after the user reboot his phone. If the user turns off his phone and turns it on an hour later, would the count down timer be 1 hour less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just run on background thread so your thread will continue to run even if app is closed.

Using service is a good idea but you have to work in background thread even in service. Because services work in foreground thread by default.

In your case I think the best way to do that is using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#). Try it.

In Both case (service and alarm) reboot will kill your thread. However you can recreate it. You can use services that will start again if they get killed. Also you can set a `BroadCastReceiver` that will be called after reboot is complete. So you can recreate your timer in `onReceive` method.

Comment: Is turning off the phone considered killing the app too? So its possible to recreate the service once the phone is rebooted?

Comment: I am not sure, you can test it. Apps like Yahoo Messenger, Viber and WhatsApp  show that it is possible to have services that will restart in any condition even if you stop them yourself!

Answer (score 1):

*

Yes it is possible. use a service , your service will continue to run even if app is closed.
 you should call a service using  AlarmManager with in a fix time .
*

Answer (score 1):

using services will be the best option for your requirement. OnFinish of the timer, you can trigger your action.